# Gazebo sensor plugins for barometric pressure Sensor with geometry_msgs/PointStamped?

Tags: ros, sensor-fusion, gazebo

Im doing some underwater UUV Gazebo simulation and would like to use the hector_pose_estimation[hector_pose_estimation](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_pose_estimation?distro=noetic) package to fuse IMU and Fluid pressure sensors input for pose estimation. But when running the node I got ERROR

```
Client [/hector_pose_estimation] wants topic /rexrov2/pressure to have datatype/md5sum [geometry_msgs/PointStamped/c63aecb41bfdfd6b7e1fac37c7cbe7bf], but our version has [sensor_msgs/FluidPressure/804dc5cea1c5306d6a2eb80b9833befe]. Dropping connection.
```

So my Pressure Sensor has `sensor_msgs/FluidPressure` but the package wants `pressure_height (geometry_msgs/PointStamped)` as input. So I created a node listening FluidPressure msg and publish the PointStamped message in the callback. Here the node

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include <sensor_msgs/FluidPressure.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/PointStamped.h>


double current_pressure;

geometry_msgs::PointStamped::ConstPtr output:
void pressureCallback(const  geometry_msgs::PointStamped::ConstPtr& msg)
{
  
     current_pressure= msg->fluid.pressure;
     depth=current_pressure / (997.04*9.8);

     output.z=depth;
     pub_.publish(output);
       
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "pressure_republisher");
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("/rexrov2/pressure", 10, pressureCallback);
  ros::Publisher pub_ = n.advertise<geometry_msgs::PointStamped>("/pressure_height"", 50);
  ros::spin();
  return 0;
}
```

Would this gonna work?

Thanks

Comment: For hector with an underwater robot, would FluidPressure be handled the same way as the expected pressure_height is currently? Could you clarify why your package uses `sensor_msgs/FluidPressure` and not the z component of `geometry_msgs/PointStamped` like the package expects? Do you use the variance field of the FluidPressure measurement? Without knowing more, it seems like the simplest answer is to just change the msg type your pkg is publishing...

Comment: because the Pressure sensor  Im using it publish the topic as sensor_msgs/FluidPressure as can see from here:  header: 
  seq: 294
  stamp: 
    secs: 44
    nsecs:         0
  frame_id: "rexrov2/pressure_link"
fluid_pressure: 232.554023891
variance: 9.0

Comment: And the hector_pose_estimation stack need Pressure message topic to be pressure_height (geometry_msgs/PointStamped). Understand?

Comment: yes, I'm asking why you don't just republish it as the geometry_msgs/PointStamped.

Comment: oh . I didnt know that I can republish it as the geometry_msgs/PointStamped. How can do that?

Comment: you could make your own node following the [pub/sub examples](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29). Obviously you'd have one node with both a publisher and subscriber. On hearing a FluidPressure msg you'd publish the PointStamped message in the callback.

Comment: ok. thanks. will do

Comment: I edit the node in the question. Is the node ok?